# How to reduce image file size while uploading multiple images using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload multiple images to the server, while uploading need to compress the file size

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile thefile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
        {
            string sfile = thefile.FileName;
            string spath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");
            string sfullpath = Path.Combine(spath, sfile);
            thefile.SaveAs(sfullpath);
        }

wanted to include the file compressing code
```

Comment: What kind of images, jpg, png, gif, tiff, raw? What kind of compression? Imgaes don't compress well with zip style compression, which is why certain formats have their own compression algorithms.

Comment: Depending on the size of the uploaded images you most likely will get request time outs when they are downscaled on the fly instead of asynchronously in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# bitmap  & ImageCodecInfo inbuilt class to compress the image.

```
 public static void Compressimage(Stream sourcePath, string targetPath, String filename)  
        {  
  
  
            try  
            {  
                using (var image = Image.FromStream(sourcePath))  
                {  
                    float maxHeight = 900.0f;  
                    float maxWidth = 900.0f;  
                    int newWidth;  
                    int newHeight;  
                    string extension;  
                    Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(sourcePath);  
                    int originalWidth = originalBMP.Width;  
                    int originalHeight = originalBMP.Height;  
  
                    if (originalWidth > maxWidth || originalHeight > maxHeight)  
                    {  
  
                        // To preserve the aspect ratio  
                        float ratioX = (float)maxWidth / (float)originalWidth;  
                        float ratioY = (float)maxHeight / (float)originalHeight;  
                        float ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);  
                        newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);  
                        newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);  
                    }  
                    else  
                    {  
                        newWidth = (int)originalWidth;  
                        newHeight = (int)originalHeight;  
  
                    }  
                    Bitmap bitMAP1 = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);  
                    Graphics imgGraph = Graphics.FromImage(bitMAP1);  
                    extension = Path.GetExtension(targetPath);  
                    if (extension == ".png" || extension == ".gif")  
                    {  
                        imgGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;  
                        imgGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;  
                        imgGraph.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);  

  
                        bitMAP1.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);  
  
                        bitMAP1.Dispose();  
                        imgGraph.Dispose();  
                        originalBMP.Dispose();  
                    }  
                    else if (extension == ".jpg")  
                    {  
  
                        imgGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;  
                        imgGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;  
                        imgGraph.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);  
                        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
                        Encoder myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;  
                        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);  
                        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);  
                        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;  
                        bitMAP1.Save(targetPath, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);  
  
                        bitMAP1.Dispose();  
                        imgGraph.Dispose();  
                        originalBMP.Dispose();  
  
                    }  
  
                   
                }  
  
            }  
            catch (Exception)  
            {  
                throw;  
  
            }  
        }  
  
  
        public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)  
        {  
  
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();  
  
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)  
            {  
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)  
                {  
                    return codec;  
                }  
            }  
            return null;  
        }  
  
    }  
}
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/85ed7a/compress-and-resize-the-image-using-web-api/